# Make webservice schema validation treat empty tags as missing

Tags: java, validation, jax-ws

I have a jaxws webservice with @SchemaValidation on it.

```
@SchemaValidation(handler = MySchemaValidationHandler.class)
@WebService(portName = "MyService", serviceName = "MyService", targetNamespace = "urn:com.my.urn", wsdlLocation = "/wsdls/mywsdl.wsdl", endpointInterface = "com.my.MyService")
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
public class MyServiceImpl
        implements MyService {
    @Resource
    WebServiceContext wsContext;
    public void myOperation(Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar> tag1, Holder<XMLGregorianCalendar> tag2, Holder<String> message) {
    ...
    }
}
```

in xsd I have the following example:

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="tag1" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xsd:element name="tag2" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

When I send the request with empty tags, I get an error concerning the field format (doesn't fit the restrictions of a date format).

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:com.my.urn">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:myOperation>
         <Tag1>value1</Tag1>
         <Tag2></Tag2>
      </urn:myOperation> 
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In request description I have mandatory tags and choice tags and have to return the correct error message in the response, so I can't just skip such errors in the handler.
Also I can't modify nor xsd nor wsdl

Logically empty tags mean the same as missing tags. How can I make the validation treat empty tags as missing or how can I delete empty tags before the validation?
Thanks.

Comment: also found the other way by using handler chain and processing the request directly as xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Don't send invalid XML. In the example you give, you should remove `<Tag2></Tag2>` in whatever your client code is. Don't try to abuse the server's validation to handle invalid XML.

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that I can't modify the schema and to provide the most tricky example with
       <xsd:choice>
     <xsd:element name="Date1" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
     <xsd:element name="Date2" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:choice>

Comment: You should update the question with more concrete examples of what exactly should be allowed and what shouldn't.

Comment: It is a best practice, but sometimes when the client code isn't yours and you can't really guarantee that it sends the valid request you need to validate it through some custom rules. 
Found that helped me - HandlerChain.